# Is it possible to access to the "list-owner" from a "list-child"?

Tags: java, list, jakarta-ee, arraylist

I have an `objectA` from `ClassA` which has a `List` of objects from `ClassB`.

Can I access `objectA` from `objectB`? I mean, I'm asking if there are something like `objectB.getListOwner()` which returns `objectA`.

I know I can have a `ClassA` atribute on `ClassB` and set it with `objectA` when I create `objectB` but I'm wondering if there are something more direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly or automatically.

What you can do is have a method in ClassA such as `addToList(ClassB objectB)`
and what this does is the following:

```
public void addToList(ClassB objectB)
{
  objectB.setClassAOwner(this);
  list.add(objectB);
}
```

And you use that method to add `ClassB` objects to the list of `ClassA`.

Obviously `ClassB` needs to have a method `setClassAOwner(ClassA owner)` and the respective member variable `ClassA` owner, and most probably a matching getter method `getClassAOwner()`

Small comment with regards to this approach. This introduces a direct cyclic dependency, which is, more often than not, undesirable from a Design principle point of view for various reasons outside scope of this question. But it achieves what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying: Can I ask a list entry what list it came from? The answer is no, you can't, there's nothing provided out-of-the-box for that. The object doesn't know what list it's on (and it could be on multiple lists, or none at all).

For example:

```
List list1 = new ArrayList();

list1.add(new Object());
list1.add(new Object());
list1.add(new Object());

for (Object o : list1) {
    doSomething(o);
}
```

There's no way for `doSomething` to figure out that the object passed to it came from `list1`, you have to create the structure for that yourself.